# Create a yellow circle on mousemove with react

Tags: reactjs, cursor, mousemove

I am trying to create a circle cursor on mousemove with react, but nothing is happening.
This is the component where I track the mouse movements:

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

  function Cursor() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);

  const logMousePosition = (e) => {
    setX(e.clientX);
    setY(e.clientY);

    e.target.setAttribute("style", "top: " + y + "px; left: " + x + "px;");

  };

  useEffect(() => {

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", logMousePosition);
  }, []);

  return <span></span>;
}

export default Cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I changed this line:

```
e.target.setAttribute("style", "top: " + y + "px; left: " + x + "px;");
```

into:

```
e.target.setAttribute("style", "top: " + e.clientY + "px; left: " + e.clientX + "px;");
```

I guess it's because now it's calculating the position of the mouse dynamically on every render.
If anyone has a better explanation I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an event handler to have it re run the function each time there is a change

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

  function Cursor() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);

  const logMousePosition = (e) => {
    setX(e.clientX);
    setY(e.clientY);

    e.target.setAttribute("style", "top: " + y + "px; left: " + x + "px;");

  };

  useEffect(() => {

    return () => { document.addEventListener("mousemove", logMousePosition)
}; }, []);
    
  

return <span></span>;
}
```

export default Cursor;